# Adding new columns to a data frame while creating new indices

Tags: pandas

Trying to dynamically create a data frame by creating a series and adding it to the frame as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

s = pd.Series({ 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'})

df['aaa'] = s
s = pd.Series({ 1: 'one', 5: 'two', 6: 'three'})

df['bbb'] = s

    aaa    bbbb
    ----   ----
1   one    one
2   two    nan
3   three  nan
```

However, this results in a frame which doesn't have the new rows corresponding to indices '5' and '6'. Is there any way can add new columns and indices if they are missing from the frame?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `concat`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
s = pd.Series({ 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'})
df['aaa'] = s
s = pd.Series({ 1: 'one', 5: 'two', 6: 'three'}, name='bbb')
df = pd.concat([df,s], axis=1)
df
Out[150]: 
     aaa    bbb
1    one    one
2    two    NaN
3  three    NaN
5    NaN    two
6    NaN  three
```